# Can't get unordered list to display horizontally

Tags: html, css, listbox

Im trying to create a nav menu, by using an unordered list, and having it then display horizontally. Each li has a div tag in it, with more divs in it, for more styling, however, the list seems to be dropping down, though not displaying anything. Here's the JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/E8jqN/2/

also, the html for it is:

```
<div id="header-right">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>
            <div class="nav-button">
                <div id="schools">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-text">
                Schools
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="nav-button">
                <div id="professors">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-text">
                Professors
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="nav-button">
                <div class="Programs">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-text">
                Programs
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="nav-button">
                <div class="account">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-text">
                My Account
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
#header-right{
    float: right;
    width: 366px;
    height: 64px;
    background-image:url('http://localhost/gradebyme/gradebyme/public/img/midtile2.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#navigation{
/*    position: relative;
    background: url('http://localhost/gradebyme/gradebyme/public/img/icontest.png');*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navigation li{
    width: 88px;
    height: 64px;
    display: inline;
}

.nav-button{
    width: 88px;
    height: 40px;
}

.nav-text{
    width: 88px;
    height: 24px;
    color:blue;
}

#schools{
    float: left;
    width: 37px;
    height: 26.75px;
/*    background-position: 0 0;*/
}

#professors{
    float: left;
    width: 37px;
    height: 26.75px;
/*    background-position: 0 -27px;*/
}

#programs{
    float: left;
    width: 37px;
    height: 26.75px;
    background-color: green;
/*    background-position: 0 -55px;*/
}

#account{
    float: left;
    width: 37px;
    height: 26.75px;
    background-color: purple;
/*    background-position: 0 -83px;*/
}
```

I need it to display them all horizontally, then I can work on adding the icons. Any help is appreciated! Also general css tips are also appreciated, Im pretty new to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontal navigation bar done in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260957/horizontal-navigation-bar-done-in-css)

Comment: You can't have DIVs inside `display: inline` elements. Make the LIs `inline-block` instead.

Comment: That worked! IF you want to put that as an answer, Ill accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navigation li{
float: right;
width: 88px;
height: 64px;}
```

or

```
#navigation li{
width: 88px;
height: 64px;
display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: float will give you less trouble, and the display: inline; would then be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap nav-buttons and nav-text with a div that has style float: left

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `float:left;` to your `#navigation li`, if I understood what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/E8jqN/7/